# Не могу сделать шапку через Bootstrap, ошибка в консоли

Tags: html, веб-программирование, bootstrap

Учусь работать в Bootstrap, решил сделать шапку сайта, на сайти в консоли кода выскакивает ошибка:

```
util.js:55 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
at util.js:55
at bootstrap.min.js:6
at bootstrap.min.js:6
```

Вот мой код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta sharset="UTF-8">
  <title>NeuralMC</title>

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="images/x-icon" href="images/rank10561041.png">

  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Neural</a>
      </div>

      <div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="activ">Меню</li>
          <li>Главное</li>
          <li>Регистр</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Если мой ответ Вам помог, обозначьте его, пожалуйста, как принятый нажатием на `v` под счётчиком голосов

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в код JQuery:

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta sharset="UTF-8">
  <title>NeuralMC</title>

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="images/x-icon" href="images/rank10561041.png">

  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Neural</a>
      </div>

      <div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="activ">Меню</li>
          <li>Главное</li>
          <li>Регистр</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```